# Modelling events for fast retrieval from persistence

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Hi I am working on a project that involves modelling events.

e.g PersonA dated PersonB, PersonB dated PersonC

and was wondering what the best way of persisting this data is to allow fast retrieval of all dates for a given person in Django, as by default to retrieve all PersonB's dates in the example above i would need an OR query where dater1 = PersonB or dater2 = PersonB?

One idea i had was to store the events both ways round so in the example above i would have

PersonA dated PersonB
PersonB dated PersonA
PersonB dated PersonC
PersonC dated PersonB

That way i can index the dater1 column and retrieve all PersonBs dates quickly.

My questions are.

a) is there a better way to do this than store all events twice

b) if not, how would i go about modifying the ORM to store the event both ways round.

I will also be using Tastypie or similar to provide an api.

Many thanks, Ed